# Creating a custom control.layers class in leaflet

Tags: javascript, maps, mapping, leaflet

I have a page that displays maps using leaflet.js with many different base layers and overlays. I'd like to have separate layer controls for selecting the base maps and the overlays, and for the controls to have different icons.

To accomplish that I'm trying to on add a setButtonClass method to leaflet's [L.control.layers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Layers.js) that I can call after placing my 2nd button on the map, which would change its class and allow me to give it different styling.

So I'd initialize the controls like this:

```
var baseLayersControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, {position: 'bottomright'});
var overlayControl = L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps, {position: 'bottomright'});
baseLayersControl.addTo(map);
overlayControl.addTo(map);
overlayControl.setButtonClass();
```

However, I can't get setButtonClass to change the class the way I want. I added this to leaflet-src.js:

```
setButtonClass: function () {
        this.className = 'leaflet-control-layers2';
    },
```

And added styling to leaflet.css for the leaflet-control-layers2 class and related classes with my new icon, but right now I'm just getting two standard layer controls on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol](https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol)? It groups and labels your layer control by base maps and overlays. I'd check there first and then see how you might be able to create two separate icons for base layers and overlays.